Creality Ender-3 S1/S1 Pro CV-Laser Engraver Module 1.6W with Anet ET4 3d printer
Any one tried to mate Creality Ender-3 S1/S1 Pro CV-Laser Engraver Module 1.6W with Anet ET4 3d printer. When tried, the laser does not fire up. Any power connection mismatch issue as one 3 pin black wire from laser module is connected to Anet board?


